# How to get an output from a list box to populate some cells

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I've created a userform with a couple of list boxes in. Listbox1 has all items in it, the user can select multiple values to then move into Listbox2. once they are in listbox2 I need them to populate some cells. With 1 list item per cell.

I'm having a pain trying to work out how to do it. So far all I've got is:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim tmpMsg As String
Dim t As Long

 tmpMsg = "Selected categories:"

For t = 1 To ListBox2.ListCount
 tmpMsg = tmpMsg & vbNewLine & ListBox2.List(t - 1)
Next

 Worksheets("Specialist Prices").Activate
    Range("a1").Select
    ActiveCell.Value = tmpMsg

End Sub
```

This populates cell A1 with the entire set of list items. but I don't know how to put 1 value in a1 then move down and put the next in A2 and so on until all items are accounted for.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you are creating one string. It has linebreaks in it, but it´s still one text. If you are not using the `tmpmsg` for something else, you could use the for-loop to populate your sheet

```
For t = 1 To ListBox2.ListCount
  Thisworkbook.sheets("Specialist Prices").Range("A" & t).value = ListBox2.List(t - 1)
Next
```

You can even do it faster by adding an array to the entire range. `ListBox2.List` is an array of values and you can paste that array into a range of cells:

```
ThisWorkbook.sheets("Specialist Prices").Cells(1,1).Resize(ListBox2.ListCount,1) = ListBox2.List
```

The `Resize` method here makes sure that the range contains the same amount of cells as there are elements in `ListBox2`. It resizes the range from 1 cell to a range of `ListBox2.ListCount` amount of rows and 1 column.